# use LIKE with array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get a list of registered users that are on the contact list of a user. Since many users save phone numbers without the international prefix so I can't use `whereIn`. I am using the last 7 digits of the user's contact phone numbers  to compare with phone numbers of users in the database to return registered users on a user's contact.

my code looks like this

```
 public function getUserContact($userNumbers){
      $numbers = array($userNumbers);

  $regUsers = User::where(function($query) use($numbers){
     foreach($numbers as $userNumber){
     $query->orWhere('phone_number', 'LIKE', '%'.$userNumber.'%');
     }
   });
   return $regUsers->get();
  
 }
```

My `$numbers` array looks like this

```
 "data": Array [
"060738,3952483,953333,5953333,3879009"
  ],
```

but I keep getting an empty array as response. What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're `$numbers` variable is an array with one string of comma delimited numbers, you should be exploding them, not wrapping in an array, try this instead:

```php
public function getUserContact($userNumbers) 
{
  $numbers = explode(",", $userNumbers);

  $regUsers = User::where(function($query) use ($numbers) {
     foreach($numbers as $userNumber) {
       $query->orWhere('phone_number', 'LIKE', '%'.$userNumber.'%');
     }
   });

   return $regUsers->get();  
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that is solved, just that it does not filter it..it returns all the record I have for phone_number. Any idea why this is?

Comment: You might need to validate the numbers first to eg. make sure they are long enough, and there's no empty values (that would return everything). Also not knowing how your storing phone numbers, you should check that you are comparing strings (not integers). Also if you're only testing the end of numbers you would want to remove the second `%`. If you have some users without a phone number, you should probably exclude those from the query first.